# Downgrading a package with older version "physically" in the repository

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, aptitude

I want to downgrade from OpenJDK Update 25 to OpenJDK Update 21.

If I look, for example, at [security.ubuntu.com](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-7/) or at [mirror.pnl.gov](http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-7/), I can see that .deb files for Update 21 are still there, however, when I use apt-cache show or aptitude, I only see Update 25 and Update 3, and if I try:

```
aptitude -s install openjdk-7-jre-headless=7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
```

I get:

```
Unable to find a version "7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1" for the package "openjdk-7-jre-headless"
```

Is there any way I can downgrade using apt tools? If the only option is dpkg, will this package be "visible" for aptitude, for example, when resolving dependencies?

Comment: First check your rdepends.  You'll have to blow those out to get the downgrade to work in a stable manner.  Then remove the package.  Then install the version you want.  Then pin it.  Then apt-get update.  Then re-install known compatible versions that you removed because of rdepends.  It's more steps than I want to make a copy paste-able answer for...but those are the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried simplier way than in the comment to the question, and it seems working for me.

I downloaded .deb file for openjdk-7-jre-headless:

```
wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
```

Then I tried:

```
dpkg -i openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
```

And got a message telling me about incompatible version of openjdk-7-jre-lib (forgot to copy the message itself, sorry)

I downloaded .deb file for openjdk-7-jre-lib:

```
wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-7/openjdk-7-jre-lib_7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb
```

Then I tried:

```
dpkg -i openjdk-7-jre-headless_7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb openjdk-7-jre-lib_7u21-2.3.9-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_all.deb
```

And it seemed to downgrade properly.

Comment: Follow up: You can prevent future upgrades of the downgraded packages (there is a reason you did the downgrade) by running this command: `sudo echo "<packagename> hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`.

Comment: to re-enable upgrades: `sudo echo "<packagename> install" | sudo dpkg --set-selections`